# How to check whether a given inequality is correct for a large span of integers?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, inequality

The inequality
$\sqrt{n+ 1}−\sqrt n < \frac{1}{\sqrt n}$

is false for all n such that $101 ≤ n ≤ 2000$. Is the statement true?

Comment: Did you meant $\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}<\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ ?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Note that 
$$\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}=\frac{\left(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}\right)\left(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}\right)}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $\sqrt{n+1} \ge \sqrt{n} + \frac{1}{\sqrt n}$ for some $n$. Square both sides to get $n + 1 \ge n + 2 + \frac 1n$ which implies $n < 0$, a contradiction.